# repeated response in filling a dictionary with user input

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, input

I am trying to create a poll where users can input their name and mountain then when the poll is complete, the code will print "*Name* would like to climb *mountain*." However, the mountain that is printed is always the mountain that is input by the last user. May I know how to rectify such that it prints diff mountains for different users? Thanks.

My code:

```
responses = {}

# set a flag to indicate that polling is active
polling_active = True

while polling_active:
    # prompt for the person's name and response
    name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
    response = input("Which mountain would you like to climb someday? ")
    
    # store the response in the dictionary
    responses[name] = response
    
    # find out if anyone else is going to take the poll
    repeat = input("Would you like to let another person respond? (yes/ no) ")
    if repeat == 'no':
        polling_active = False
        
# polling is complete. show the results.
print("\n--- Poll Results ---")
for name, reponse in responses.items():
    print(name + " would like to climb " + response + ".")
```

Results:

```
What is your name? Amelia
Which mountain would you like to climb someday? Everest
Would you like to let another person respond? (yes/ no) yes

What is your name? Bobby
Which mountain would you like to climb someday? Matterhorn
Would you like to let another person respond? (yes/ no) no

--- Poll Results ---
Amelia would like to climb Matterhorn.
Bobby would like to climb Matterhorn.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo , in last 2 lines, change `reponse`

```
for name, reponse in responses.items():
    print(name + " would like to climb " + reponse + ".")
```